# What is the advantage of Greibach Normal Form over Chomsky Normal Form?

Tags: formal-grammars

I wanted to know the pros and cons of Chomsky normal form and Greibach normal form.

Comment: In what context? These normal forms are often helpful to prove results on context-free languages, but I'm not sure they have any practical currency.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually several variants for these normal forms, so it might be useful to first recall the definitions. A context-free grammar is in *Chomsky normal form* if all of its production rules are of the form:

> 1. $X \to YZ$
> 2. $X \to a$
> 3. $S \to 1$

where $X, Y$ and $Z$ are nonterminal symbols, $S$ is the start symbol, $a$ is a letter and $1$ is the empty word. A grammar is in *Chomsky reduced form* if its productions are of the form 1 or 2, but with $X$ and $Y$ being possibly equal to the start symbol.
The Chomsky Normal Form has been used to give a **polynomial-time parsing algorithm** (the [CYK algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm)).

A grammar is in *Greibach normal form* if its productions are of the form

> 1. $X \to aX_1 \dotsm X_k$
> 2. $X \to b$

where $X, X_1, \dots, X_k$ are nonterminal symbols and $a$, $b$ are letters. It is in *Greibach quadratic normal form* if $k \leqslant 2$ in all rules. It is in *Greibach two sided normal form* if its productions are of the form

> 1. $X \to aX_1 \dotsm X_kb$
> 2. $X \to c$

where $X, X_1, \dots, X_k$ are nonterminal symbols and $a$, $b$, $c$ are letters. It is in *Greibach quadratic two sided normal form* (or *Hotz normal form*) if $k \leqslant 2$ in all rules. These normal forms have important **applications in formal language theory**. See for instance the article [Towards an algebraic theory of context-free languages](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~berstel/Articles/1996AlgebraicTheory.pdf).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment. However, I wanted to know the advantage of GNF over the CNF. Any specific usage of GNF where CNF can not be used.

Comment: Related. http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/10468/the-importance-of-normal-forms-like-chomsky-normal-form-for-cfgs . Converting to Greibach normal form seems to enable easier PDA construction, not totally sure yet tho.